# Can't replace Featured Image on Oxygen

Tags: css, wordpress, image, background

I'm currently working on a clients website in which was built in Oxygen before they came to us. I'm trying to change a case study image so that on the all posts page it has a unique image with its name underneath.

I've removed the featured image and replaced it with the new one but it is still set to a different image using the css background property.

Does anyone have any idea of where I could go to change the image of this case study post? I've tried countless things, but all I'm left with right now is hardcoding the css to set that specific post to a different background image. But there must be somewhere it lives to resolve this issue.

[CSS Background Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bUa7.png)

Things I've tried and my current summary:
I tried replacing the featured image but it didn't seem to change or alter in any way shape or form. I've looked in different areas but as I've never used oxygen I'm clueless on where to look next. My only option currently is to hardcode it to change the background image in the CSS

Update: I've also checked the Link Wrapper background image in Oxygen but there is no image set there.